# Magento image to permanently display by external url

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images, magento-community

My client's site is using Magento version ce-1.9.2.0.

Now he wants the product's(and probably category's also in future) images to be fetched and displayed by external URL instead of traditional way of storing images in site directories.

Can anybody suggest any way/plugin for achieving this along with resize image working ?

Resized image can be stored on site folders.

Comment: Do you mean you would like to use a content delivery network or external content storage site for storing images?

Comment: Yes, could be an option, but most probably the images from would be from client's external server so he doesn't have to move images from that server to the site's server.

Comment: This answer might be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293465/how-to-use-external-urls-for-product-images-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

Here is some hints for you:

1. Create the product attribute of type text, say: external_url_base
2. Similarly repeat for small, thumbnail & gallery images

> Basically, it's like mimic'ing the Magento's default media attributes
>   but with type: text

3. Develop some public methods to get all types of images
4. And use those methods in frontend templates

   - catalog/product/list.phtml
   - catalog/product/view.phtml
   - catalog/product/view/media.phtml
   - ...